# C# - CosmosDB Query Definition array_contains

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following query in my cosmosdb database:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.AlertsConfiguration, {"Code":@alertCode, "isEnabled":true}, true)
```

which is working well.

The problem is that I need to execute this query from my C# project and I do it this way:

```
 var results = new List<User>();

 var queryResult = _usersContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<User>(new QueryDefinition(QueryHelper.GetUsersForAlert)
                    .WithParameter("alertCode", alertCode));

                while (queryResult.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var response = await queryResult.ReadNextAsync();

                    results.AddRange(response.ToList());
                }

                return results;
```

the `GetUsersForAlert` query is this one:

```
$"SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.AlertsConfiguration, {{'Code':@alertCode, 'isEnabled':true}}, true)";
```

When I execute it on the code it returns a Bad request 400 error

I'm sure the problem is in this last syntaxis, I've tried several ways but I always get error, any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

The query is fine but to substitute the parameter you need to include the `@` in the name. So your `WithParameter` should look like this:

```
.WithParameter("@alertCode", alertCode)
```